# how use model for where query in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.5

Hy!

i am using where query and check where user is exist or not in my login system and save the data in a variable $user and then i compact this variable to my view to get the name of logged in user but the query just return in my variable 1 or 0.
what i do. how can I use model for such type of queries please guide me..
here is my little code....

```html
$user = new user();

        $user = DB::table('users')->where('name', $request->name)->first() && DB::table('users')->where('password', $request->password)->first() ;



        if($user==null){

            return redirect('/login');

        }

        return view('user.dashboard',compact('user'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are performing Boolean logic in that long line assigning to $user, hence the true/false you're seeing.

```
 // using eloquent 
 if ( $user = User::where(['name' => $request->name, 'password' => Hash::make($request->password)])->first()) {
     return view('user.dashboard',compact('user'));
 }

 return redirect('/login');
```